# How to transform array of arrays into grouped arrays containing key and values?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

Following is the input array:

```
$input = [
    [
        'id' => 96,
        'shipping_no' => 212755-1,
        'part_no' => 'reterty',
        'description' => 'tyrfyt',
        'packaging_type' => 'PC'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 96,
        'shipping_no' => 212755-1,
        'part_no' => 'dftgtryh',
        'description' => 'dfhgfyh',
        'packaging_type' => 'PC'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 97,
        'shipping_no' => 212755-2,
        'part_no' => 'ZeoDark',
        'description' => 's%c%s%c%s',
        'packaging_type' => 'PC'
    ]
];
```

I want the above to be transformed into like this:

```
$output = [
    [
        'key' => 96, 
        'value' => [
            [
                'shipping_no' => 212755-1, 
                'part_no' => 'reterty', 
                'description' => 'tyrfyt', 
                'packaging_type' => 'PC'
            ], 
            [
                'shipping_no' => 212755-1, 
                'part_no' => 'dftgtryh', 
                'description' => 'dfhgfyh', 
                'packaging_type' => 'PC'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'key' => 97, 
        'value' => [
            [
                'shipping_no' => 212755-2, 
                'part_no' => 'ZeoDark', 
                'description' => 's%c%s%c%s', 
                'packaging_type' => 'PC'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have tried to implement it like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $result[] = ['key' => $value['id'], 'value' => ['shipping_no' => $value['shipping_no'], 'part_no' => $value['part_no'], 'description' => $value['description'], 'packaging_type' => $value['packaging_type']]];
}
```

It is not getting grouped based on common key. Please help me with the possible approach that I should take to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you've done a good job of crafting the new subarray structure, but the grouping should come first and because of how the grouping is done with temporary keys, the restructuring code can be simplified.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QAIG3))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    unset($row['id']);
    if (isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id]['value'][] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$id] = [
            'key' => $id,
            'value' => [$row]
        ];
    }
}
var_export(
    array_values($result)
);
```

To explain the process:

1. As you iterate the input array, cache the `id` of each encountered row of data.
2. Because you do not wish to retain the `$row['id']` in your `value` subarray, you can now safely remove that element from the `$row`.
3. Then check if there is an existing group for the current `$id` with `isset($result[$id])`.
4. If the group already exists, then you can merely push the `$row` data as a new indexed row into the group's `value` subarray.
5. If the group does not already exist, then it needs to have all of the desired structure declared/populated.  This means that the `key` element is declared and the `value` subarray must be declared with its first entry.
6. Finally, if you don't want the first level keys remove them with `array_values()`.